# Build android from source. Battery power incorrect

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-7, battery-life

I added a kernel module to the msm flo kernel. I built android JB from source for my Nexus 7(flo). I flashed the device with the built OS.

My battery power seems to be stuck at 100% remaining. I also used the trepn profiler app for Qualcomm SOCs and it also gives incorrect measurements for  % battery power remaining and instantaneous battery power.

When I flash a factory image of JB 4.3 this issue goes away. Is there a part of the source tree that is responsible for giving correct battery power measurements? If so where is it located?

I booted into recovery and the battery power stats are still incorrect

Comment: If you changed something at the source code, most likely the issue is to be found there. I assume that a clean repo sync of the source tree with no changes would work properly.
If you would like some help, some information would be nice to have.
Which kernel module?
From which source you pulled the source?
Is anything to be found in the build logs?

Comment: I added a kernel module to msm/drivers/gpu. It basically is a new gpu pwrscale policy. The existing policy is trustzone which can be found under drivers/gpu/msm/kgsl_pwrscale_trustzone.c

From what I know, the battery power measurements are through the files in drivers/power which I didn't change at all.

It was a clean repo sync of JB 4.3_r3